# OPENFILENAME stopping ifstream from working

Tags: c++, mfc

I a making a simple utility to convert a CSV file to an EDL but I am running into a strange bug that is stumping me. I am trying to get the filename and the open the file, if I comment out the first part, as in the example below, the second part works. If I run the fist part, it gets a filename successfully but without even passing the file name gathered but still stating it explicitly "C:\santor_4k.csv", the myReadFile.open does not open the file. The out file still works fine, it just never gets into the if (myReadFile.is_open()) loop.

```
void CMFCApplication3Dlg::OnBnClickedButtonOpen()
{

    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    /*OPENFILENAME ofn;       // common dialog box structure
    char szFile[260];       // buffer for file name
    HWND hwnd;              // owner window
    HANDLE hf;              // file handle

    // Initialize OPENFILENAME
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    //ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
    // Set lpstrFile[0] to '\0' so that GetOpenFileName does not 
    // use the contents of szFile to initialize itself.
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "CSV\0*.CSV\0";
    //ofn.lpstrFilter = "All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0";
    ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

    // Display the Open dialog box. 

    if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == TRUE)
        hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile,
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        (HANDLE)NULL);

    m_EchoText.Format(szFile);*/

    int counter = 0;
    int lastfcc = 0;
    int fcc;
    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("C:\\santor_4k.csv");
    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("C:\\santor_4k_r3_resolve.edl", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
    char output[260];
    //resolve
    cout << "TITLE: ( no title )" << endl << endl;
    outfile << "TITLE: ( no title )" << endl << endl;
    //revival
    //outfile << "TITLE: ( no title )" << endl;
    //outfile << "FCM: NON - DROP FRAME"<<endl << endl;;
    if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
        while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
            int first;
            int second;
            char lastTC[40];
            myReadFile >> output;
            //cout << int(output[0]) << endl;
            if (int(output[0]) > 47 && int(output[0]) < 58)
            {// cout << output << endl; 
                std::string str = output;
                std::size_t found = str.find(",");
                if (found != std::string::npos){
                    //cout <<"first comma" << found << endl; 
                    first = found + 1;
                }
                found = str.find(",", found + 1);
                if (found != std::string::npos) {
                    //cout << "second comma" << found << endl; 
                    second = found - first;
                }
                std::string  fccstring = str.substr(first, second);
                //cout << "fccString=" << fccstring<<endl;
                fcc = stoi(fccstring); //+1 for revival ?
                toTimeCode(lastfcc);
                strcpy_s(lastTC, timecode);
                toTimeCode(fcc);
                cout << setfill('0') << setw(3) << counter << "  001      V     C " << lastTC << " " << timecode << " " << lastTC << " " << timecode << " " << endl << endl;
                //resolve
                if (counter>0)outfile << setfill('0') << setw(3) << counter << "  001      V     C " << lastTC << " " << timecode << " " << lastTC << " " << timecode << " " << endl << endl;
                //revival
                //if (counter>0)outfile << setfill('0') << setw(3) << counter << "   title     V     C " << lastTC << " " << timecode << " " << lastTC << " " << timecode<<"\r";

                lastfcc = fcc;
                counter++;
            }


        }
    }
    myReadFile.close();
    outfile.close();
    //std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue...";
    //std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

Comment: If the issue is not able to read/open/write a file, you don't have to show all of this code.  Just do a simple open/close, or write a couple of bytes to a file and then see if that works.  Wading through all of that code after the `GetOpenFileName` is a little too much...

Answer (score 0):

What do you get in `szFile` after doing `GetOpenFileName(&ofn)`? You should also `memset(szFile, 0, sizeof(szFile));` before calling `GetOpenFileName`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own problem, I guess you should never copy an example without understanding it, this part:

if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn) == TRUE)
        hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile,
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        (HANDLE)NULL);

opens a file already so when I whet to open it again, it didn't work. By removing it, I solved the problem